# How do I read the Entity Framework Model and validate it against a given connection?

Tags: database, unit-testing, entity-framework

I have a Entity Framework Database First Model.

I want to write a MSTest/nUnit test to verify that all the stored procs, tables and views that are defined in my edmx model are still valid on the database.

Comment: My stored procedures & tables may exist in a different schema, other than dbo.

Comment: I know how to check the database for existence. I need to get the list from EF to check.

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847192/how-do-i-write-a-test-to-verify-entity-framework-database-first-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
var list = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EdmFunction>(DataSpace.SSpace).Where(i=>i.ReturnParameter == null);
```

This returned the correct schema and stored procedure name. I then could call for each item in the list:

```
var sqlCommands = string.Format("SELECT 'x' FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'{0}') AND type in (N'P', N'PC')", storedProcedureName);
var exists = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sqlCommands).Any();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Query the [system tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179932.aspx).**  This will verify the presence of all of the required objects in your database.

For example, the following query uses the sys.objects catalog view to return all database objects that have been modified in the last 10 days.

```
SELECT name AS object_name 
  ,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
  ,type_desc
  ,create_date
  ,modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE modify_date > GETDATE() - 10
ORDER BY modify_date;
```

**See Also**
[Querying the SQL Server System Catalog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
[ADO.NET Code Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  It is a legitimate solution, probably the best one.

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but my issue is with getting the list of SP, tables and views from EF.

Comment: @Brian: The system tables are just ordinary SQL tables, like all the others. If EF can't handle that, then write some pedestrian ADO.NET code to accomplish it.  Remember, EF is for your CRUD; don't expect EF to handle one hundred percent of your application's operation.  That's why you have SP's in the first place.

Comment: I'm looking for calling a .Net method to get a list of objects defined in my model, then I can execute your SQL to verify the existence of the stored procedure. Its the .net side I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: There's some ADO.NET code examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can use to execute the query.

Comment: Again, thats not the question I'm asking. I'm trying to get the list of objects from Entity Framework.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3892926) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463415)

Comment: Those almost have it. I can get a list of the tables and stored procedures.But I'm not getting the schema where the tables and procs are contained, most of my objects are not in dbo

Comment: That's why you need the system tables to fill in the blanks.

Comment: if I have 2 or more tables in the different schemas with the same name. I won't know which schema to verify against. EF has to know which schema to execute or select from I've seen it in the SQL Trace. I just want to be able to grab it without reading the XML of the edmx file.

Comment: You don't need the edmx to read the system table.  Perhaps you should write a detailed question about exactly what you want (including all of the information that is relevant to your specific problem), and post it to Stack Overflow.